# Chomecast device has an synchronization issue between audio and video signals when seeking to pre-defined playback position

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, exoplayer

I am using CastPlayer class of Exoplayer which supports casting to chromecast device in my Android app and a default CAF receiver app of Chomecast.
Everything works fine when I cast a video at a position of beginning (below variable positionMs is 0).

```
loadItem(com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaQueueItem item, long positionMs)
```

But when I cast my video at pre-defined position which is much higher than 0 (e.g: positonMs=1800000 ~ 30 mins), chromecast will show below synchronization issue between audio and video signals. 
1. Sometime, video signal is faster or slower than audio signal and vice versa.
2. Sometime, video signal is frozen with audio (but sounds abnormally)
3. Sometime, video and audio signal is fine.

Have anybody faced the same issue and is there any solution for this?

P/S: I am testing on chromecast ultra 4K & chomecast 2nd devices.

Thank you for your attention & help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current workaround for this issue is to use custom CAF receiver app with adding below code into it to synchronize audio and video signals once starting casting a video. And then issue is solved.

```
    onceTime = 0;
    context.getPlayerManager().addEventListener(
        cast.framework.events.EventType.BUFFERING, (event) => {
        if (onceTime==0){
            context.getPlayerManager().seek(context.getPlayerManager().getCurrentTimeSec()+1);
            context.getPlayerManager().seek(context.getPlayerManager().getCurrentTimeSec()-1);
            onceTime = 1;
        }
    });
```